# How to disable a button with asp.net after certain conditions? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to disable a button that creates a document when the values I inserted was not recalculated.
I tried something like this:

```
        private void EnableButton()
        {
            button.Enabled = true;
            button.Style.Remove("Opacity");
        }
        private void DisableButton()
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            //button.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled"); 
            //button.Attributes.Add("disabled","true");
            button.Style.Add("Opacity", ".5");
        }
```

On Localhost, the 3 methods works, and it is disable and enable correctly. But on client side, even if the opacity works, the button is still clickable.
I searched before asking, but could not find the solution. There is a way to verify if the button is enabled or not and disable it on asp.net file??
The button on asp.net:

```
<LinkButton ID="button" runat="server" Text="Save" Style="float: right"
    OnClick="button_save" ImageCssClass="button">
```

Comment: Use property binding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: a web app right ?, from what I understand you are trying to activate and deactivate the button by the controller, the best way to do that will be through a jquery, it will be much easier

Comment: Set CausesValidation="false"